What does it mean to say "possible in reality?"
Consider the following truth table.



I am hungry
My eyes are closed




0
0


0
1


1
0


1
1



Each row is possible.  But that seems to me like an incomplete statement.  Instead, I think it makes more sense to say each row is possible in reality.  But this leads me to my question.  What is meant by saying something is possible in reality?
I might be hungry in the current moment in time, or I might not be hungry in the current moment in time.  Similarly, my eyes might be closed in the current moment in time, or my eyes might not be closed in the current moment in time.
So reality in the context of my question seems to have something to do with the current moment in time.  But this raises additional questions like "what is time", "does 'the current moment in time' make sense according to the theory of relativity?".
Let A be a statement.  A statement symbolizes a proposition. A proposition is true or false but not true and false simultaneously.  The word 'simultaneously' thus falls in the domains of logic and physics.
Let |A| mean the current truth value of the proposition denoted by A.
|A|=1 means the proposition denoted by A is currently true.
Thus Einstein's theory affects the meaning of 'truth' as well.
Although I have raised many questions, I am only concerned with one.  What does it mean to say something is possible in reality.  The notion of 'possible' falls in the domain of modal logic, which Einstein was unfamiliar with.  So answers using SQML will be most appreciated.

You are asking us to tell you what you mean by a phrase you made up?

"Possible" does mean "in reality". Outside of reality, anything goes. Or you could ask "are all these four states possible in Dungeons and Dragons?"

Please define "reality". People ask questions about "god", without stopping to consider what other people understand by "god" (which is supposedly beyond human understanding, and therefore impossible to define). In both cases, they are subjective, because understanding changes during your lifetime.

@WeatherVane, I wanted philosophers to use my example truth table to figure out the meaning of reality in that phrase to see if anyone came up with my answer, which is Reality is the current moment in time.

That's opinion: nobody knows what 'reality' is. It's 42. Nobody can get right to the point where all this stuff is generated, moment by moment. My point was that our understanding of what reality is changes through life: reality is not the same now as when I was a child. Therefore 'reality' is subjective. Good luck with figuring out the meaning of reality from a truth table of four options.

@Weathervane, How do you know "nobody knows what reality is", you are not everybody.  True, you can say I don't know what reality is ", but that's not even the crux of my question.  There's a modal component to it.  What does "POSSIBLE in reality " mean.  I was expecting answers based on the truth table, and SQML.

Because every now and then some understanding comes along to knock our sense of reality. The world isn't flat. The universe is not geocentric. There are smaller particles than atoms. My father isn't my father.  And so on. All we have is a model of reality which is different for everbody (although they overlap).

@WeatherVane, when the universe makes sense to you, with no effort, that let's you know your model is the correct one, and that your mind is "in reality".  By that phrase, reality is the set of true propositions.  That's a different usage of the word 'reality' than the truth table meaning.

Well, the universe does make sense from time to time, and then we are content – until there are new facts or events to disturb it. But it's your model: subjective. It's more likely that you are in a fool's paradise , because it is ephemeral.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You say:

I think it makes more sense to say each row is possible in reality. But this leads me to my question. What is meant by saying something is possible in reality?

Only you can know what you mean by the phrase "possible in reality" such that it makes more sense to say that than merely "possible."
We cannot tell you what you mean when you say that.

use your nterpretation of the truth table to assign the phrase "possible in reality" a meaning that is the same or different from mine
